# how to execute a linq query in association table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework.

I have 3 tables.

Candidats : Id,cin
Poste : Id
PosteCandidats : candidat_id, poste_id

I want to get a candidat that has (cin= 'abc15' and poste_id = 3)

My models :

```
   public class Candidat
   {
     public int Id { set; get; }
     public string num_cin    { set; get; }
     public ICollection<Poste> postes { get; set; }
   }

    public class Poste
    {
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string poste_name {set;get}
    public List<Candidat> candidats {set;get;}
   }
```

That generates an association table PosteCandidats.

i  tried  this   :

I tried this but it gives me an error

```
         var v = _db.Candidats
            .Where(c => c.num_cin == "abc15"
            && c.postes.Any(pc => pc.Id == 3));
            var candi = v.SingleOrDefault();
```

but it gives me nothing

(I think the problem is with  Any() method )

Comment: This looks like working code. What is the error? (Never just say "an error")

Comment: your are right  the  problem  that  i  have is  in  the modelview  because  i'm passing to models  to a view  so i did not  anderstand  that  well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 samples that both work:

```
var lCandidat = new List<Candidat>();

lCandidat.Add(new Candidat{ Id = 2, num_cin = "xabc", postes = new Collection<Poste>()
{
    new Poste {Id = 10, poste_name = "id10"},
    new Poste {Id = 15, poste_name = "id15"}
}});

lCandidat.Add(new Candidat{ Id = 1, num_cin = "abc15", postes = new Collection<Poste>()
{
    new Poste {Id = 3, poste_name = "3"},
    new Poste {Id = 4, poste_name = "id4"}
}});


//get candidat
var v = (from c in lCandidat
    where c.num_cin == "abc15"
          && c.postes.Any(p => p.Id == 3)
    select c)
    .SingleOrDefault();


var v2 = lCandidat.Where(c => c.num_cin == "abc15"
                          && c.postes.Any(p => p.Id == 3))
                         .Select(c => c).SingleOrDefault();



Console.WriteLine("v query ID {0}, cin {1}", v.Id, v.num_cin);
Console.WriteLine("v2 query ID {0}, cin {1}", v2.Id, v2.num_cin);
```

Result:

```
v query ID 1, cin abc15
v2 query ID 1, cin abc15
```